# Getting a function's module of original definition

Tags: python, python-import

Given a class or function, is there a way to find the full path of the module where it is originally defined?  (I.e. using `def xxx` or `class xxx`.)

I'm aware that there is `sys.modules[func.__module__]`.  However, if `func` is imported in a package's `__init__.py`, then `sys.modules` will simply redirect to that `__init__.py`, because the function has been brought into that namespace, as far as my understanding goes.

A concrete example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sys

>>> np.broadcast.__module__
'numpy'

>>> sys.modules[np.broadcast.__module__]
<module 'numpy' from '/Users/brad/.../site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>
```

Obviously, `broadcast` is not defined in `__init__.py`; it is just brought into the namespace with one of [these](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/__init__.py#L158) `from module import *` statements.

It would be nice to see where in the source `np.broadcast` is defined (regardless of the file extension, be it .c or .py).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding:

> However, if `func` is imported in a package's  `__init__.py`, then
>   `sys.modules` will simply redirect to that `__init__.py`, because the
>   function has been brought into that namespace, as far as my
>   understanding goes.

is wrong. `__init__.py` importing a thing has no effect on that thing's `__module__`.

The behavior you're seeing with `numpy.broadcast` happens because C types don't really have a "defining module" the same way types written in Python do. `numpy.broadcast.__module__ == 'numpy'` because `numpy.broadcast` is [written in C](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/iterators.c#L1728) and declares its name to be `"numpy.broadcast"`, and a C type's `__module__` is determined from its name.

As for how to get a class or function's "module of original definition", the best you really have is `__module__` and other functions that go through `__module__`.