# Why '__module__' class attribute can differ from actual module, where class was defined?

Tags: python, numpy, module, python-module

I'm trying to understand modules concept in python, therefore I'm trying to make some experiments to understand details more deeper :)

So, I see, that `ndarray` is defined in `numpy.core.multiarray` module initially. In my opinion, its `__module__` attribute have to be `numpy.core.multiarray`, but actually it is `numpy`. Why does it happen?

I'm using Python 3 and numpy 1.14.3.
Code to reproduce is:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.ndarray.__module__
'numpy'
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: `multiarray` is a compiled file (`.so`).  Overall `numpy` is a complex mix of Python and compiled code, so the usual descriptions of Python modules and classes don't apply.  Work with something simpler, that's defined in one Python file.

Comment: @hpaulj Can you answer very briefly for my two qeustions, please?
1. Yes, I know, that multiarray is precompiled. Is there some another logic for `__module__` attribute for precompiled files?
2. Or in this case of `ndarray`, was `__module__` set manually somewhere?
Thank you!

Comment: [Relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139674/getting-a-functions-module-of-original-definition)

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you! This should be accepted answer :)